# My Ubuntu 14.04 window controls don't changes after setting in dconf-editor

Tags: unity

How to change window-controls in ubuntu 14.04? It's not changing. Please help me.

Comment: Please add some screenshots to your question: where did you change settings?

Comment: report the bug at launchpad, 14.04 is still in beta.

Comment: Did you the mean position(left/right) of window-control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04,Unity uses new unity-window-decorator where this feature is not implemented. This is a design decision. Ubuntu uses window-control on left on panel. There is no reason to have it on right on normal window. However developers are open to accept any patches.

You can file a bug for Unity on launchpad.